# Storing JSON in Postgres as BYTEA or other types

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I need to have a generic key-value data-store in Postgres and Sqlite3. I originally planned to store this as a `JSONB` type but the SQL statements I execute needs to be compatible with both Postgres and Sqlite3. Since sqlite doesn't support `jsonb`, I planned to use `BYTEA` instead. So something like this:

**Originally:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data JSONB
)
```

**Now**

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    data BYTEA
)
```

This is not the best but it's still fine since I thought I could just cast `BYTEA` to `JSON` during query. That is, I thought I could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT data::json ->> 'name' AS name from foo where id = $1;
```

But looks like I cannot cast `BYTEA` to `JSON` type (`ERROR:  cannot cast type bytea to json`). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188275/converting-bytea-to-json) post describes how to convert `BYTEA` to `JSON`. But I'm worried that the `decode()` and `convert_from()` functions are going to be expensive.

So now I'm considering storing this data as `VARCHAR` instead of `BYTEA`, which eliminates the need for the `decode()` and `convert_from()` functions.

I'm wondering what the best option is here and if there's any better methods given the constraints I described.

Comment: Does SQLite really support the same syntax on JSON function as Postgres? If not you are going to have different SQL queries anyway. Having different CREATE TABLE statements seems the much smaller problem to solve. I would go for a `jsonb` column in Postgres and a `text` column in SQLite

Comment: The database initialization happens through a C++ program, I'm not in control of the underlying interface that interacts with the databases. My understanding is that Postgres and SQLite support mostly the same syntax except for a few caveats. `jsonb` is one of them. Essentially, this program run unit tests with SQLite and runs in production with Postgres.

Comment: why not 'text' type?

Comment: Sure, `text` type. It think it'd still be the same thing as `varchar` though.

Comment: in postgresql text and varchar are different, in sqlite varchar(255) is converted to text,  https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-character.html   I'm with the jjanes use text type,  it has the least issues trying to maintain db portability

Comment: on postgresql Text and Bytea use the same storage mechanics TOAST over a certain size, as does JSON,

Comment: I'm going to read into TOAST, but is it applied per row or per table? If there's 8000 rows in a table, each with a `TEXT` field containing 1 byte of data (aggregating to a total of 8 kB), will TOAST be applied? Or is this only applicable when one row contains 8 kB of data?

Comment: @zsheep: in Postgres text and varchar are **not** different at all

Comment: @thestateofmay: TOAST is applied to a single column. If the **column** value exceeds about 2K it will be compressed and stored out of line. But that doesn't concern you on the SQL level. And I am pretty sure that SQLite does not support the same syntax for accessing JSON values as Postgres does.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes varchar is different  by the nature it has a limit, text can grow to the limit of TOAST. 1gb.  From the manual The notations varchar(n) and char(n) are aliases for character varying(n) and character(n), respectively. character without length specifier is equivalent to character(1)

Comment: @zsheep: `text` and `varchar` (not `varchar(n)`) are **exactly** the same thing. And values are always stored in exactly the same way regardless which variant of the definition you use. The only difference when using `varchar(n)` is, that a constraint on the length is enforced. A value of `'abcd'`  is stored in exactly the same in a `text`, `varchar`, `varchar(742)` or `varchar(4)` column. There is also no difference in performance

Comment: I think postgresql is the only DB that  aliases varchar to text.  Which i completely forgot,  and i assumed everyone would  consider varchar  =varchar(n)....   Yes i know there is no performance difference between the different types

Comment: if you're using postgresql in production it seems that the best solution would be to run unit tests against postgresql, as this would allow access to postgresql features

Answer (score 0):

I have same setup and successfully extracted data with

```
SELECT encode(data, 'escape')::jsonb->'name'
FROM   foo
```

Comment: I guess that could work so long as you don;t have any values containing 0x22 `"`  eg: `{"name": "Jesse \"The Body\" Ventura"}`